# What geometric transformation does this matrix apply on $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If a linear transformation has a matrix $$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},$$

then what geometric transformation does it apply on $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I have no clue. I could figure out what the transformation looks like in terms of coordinates, which is $T(x,y,z) = (-x,3y,0)$ but what should I do from here? I can see that $z-$coordinate of any point is becoming zero so every point must be projected to $xy$ plane. Is it projecting every vector on the line $x=3y$? My coordinate geometry knowledge sucks so I can't confirm it.

Can I get any help, please?

**Edit :** We can see that $T$ sends $(x,y,z) \to (-x,3y,0)$. So if I try to find the parametric form of the image then it is like : $$ r = -x, r= 3y \\
            \implies  x= -3y$$.
So we can say that $T$ projects every point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the line $x=-3y$. Is that correct???

Comment: Well, $A$ projects everything onto $xy$ plane and then stretches $y$ coordinate $3$ times, and then symmetrically reflects $x$ to $-x$ (reflects relatively $y$ line)

Comment: @NeoFanatic can you tell me if I have to answer it formally, say on an exam or I have to give someone else an answer, then how do I formally put it? Can you please write an formal answer?

Comment: Have a look on what it does to basis, feed the vector [ 1, 0 , 0 ]^T , [ 0,1,0,]^T etc into it

Comment: @666User666 I did that but from there I found that it sends the basis to $\{(-1,0,0),(0,3,0)\}$. But what now?

Comment: How you can see that every vector $a(1, 0, 0) + b(0, 1,0) + c(0, 0, 1)$ goes to $(-a, 3b, 0)$. I don't know, what to add

Comment: You can watch the [3B1B-The change of basis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2LTAUO1TdA&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&index=13) and [Linear Transformation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&index=3) may this will help you get the intuition behind the scaling of $\hat i$ and $\hat j$
Also, I like to suggest curious people: You can watch all videos on [*Essence Linear Algebra*](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab)

Comment: @I_don't_know_maths_ thanks for the suggestion.  I'll definitely see all the videos. If you have similar suggestions on topics like topology, calculus, real analysis and abstract algebra then do share the links. :)

Comment: @Itachi Well, I don't know about the topology but for [Linear Algebra-MIT Open Course by Sir Gilbert Strang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK3O402wf1c&list=PL49CF3715CB9EF31D&index=1) and for calculus I believe I'm not the right person to answer/provide good links.

Answer (score 1):

How we write the matrix $A$ of linear transform $T: V \longrightarrow V$ of vector space $V$ with fixed basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$? If $T(e_1) = w_1, \ldots T(v_n) = w_n$, then the matrix $A = [w_1, \ldots, w_n]$. In your example:
$$T(1, 0, 0) = (-1, 0, 0) \\
T(0, 1, 0) = (0, 3, 0)\\
T(0, 0, 1) = (0, 0, 0)$$

So it projects $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto $xy$ plane, then reflects $x$ line to $-x$ line and then stratches $y$ line to $3y$ line.

Comment: can you check my edit??

Comment: Your edit is wrong. You don't need parametric stuff or something like that, just forget about it, only think about how transform acts on basis, and by linearity it acts on all vector space

Comment: @Itachi *So it projects R3 onto XY-plane, then reflects x line to −x line and then stretches y line to 3y line.* I believe this answers your question you can use [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/3d?lang=en) or else simply close your eyes and start imagining the beauty of the Cartesian coordinate system.